# Code inside SKAction completion block not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, sprite-kit, skaction

I've implemented a "pause menu" in my game. When the user taps the pause button on the top left corner of the screen, I run the following code:

```
- (void) pauseGame
{
    // Blur the game's contents:
    [_effectNode setShouldEnableEffects:YES];

    // Apply cover:
    [_pauseLayer addChild:_pauseCover]; // (_pauseLayer sits just above _effectNode)

    // Start from fully transparent...
    [_pauseCover setAlpha:0.0f]; // Start from fully transparent...

    // ...and animate to near-opaque:
    [_pauseCover runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.85f duration:0.125f]];
}
```

to un-pause, I do this:

```
- (void) unpauseGame
{
    // Un-blur game contents
    [_effectNode setShouldEnableEffects:NO];

    // Fade cover out
    [_pauseLayer runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0f
                                        duration:0.125f]
                completion:^(void){
                    // The following lines are executed, but still 
                    // the button below doesn't receive any more touches

                    [_pauseLayer removeAllChildren];// Neither
                    [_pauseCover removeFromParent]  // of these
                    [_pauseLayer setHidden:YES];    // makes a difference

                }];
}
```

After un-pausing, the node hierarchy is exactly the same as before (I logged it). However, the pause button, once covered by `_pauseLayer` (of type `SKNode`) and its child `_pauseCover` (of type `SKSpriteNode`) no longer receives touch input (the game scene itself, does).

If instead of removing the cover on the fade action's completion block, I do it right away, or using `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, like this:

```
- (void) unpauseGame
{
    // Un-blur game contents:
    [_effectNode setShouldEnableEffects:NO];

    // Fade cover out to fully transparent:
    [_pauseLayer runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0f
                                        duration:0.125f]];

    [_pauseLayer performSelector:@selector(removeAllChildren) 
                      withObject:nil
                      afterDelay:0.25]; // a bit longer than fade, just in case
}
```

...Then, after resuming, the button works just as before... I know SKSpriteNode instances block touch events (even with `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO`), but the sprites are no longer there! Puzzling!

**NOTE** I must stress that the completion block **does** get executed (breakpoints stop there), and logging the removed children after that **gives the proper count** (0). However, the pause button (a sprite subclass that implements the `-touches*: withEvent:`  methods) no longer receives touches.

---

***SOLUTION:*** 
I never quite got to accomplish what I wanted: Have a bunch of "placeholder" nodes acting as layers (levels) persisting at fixed depths, and then add/remove children to them as necessary (in this case, the cover sprite/dialogs). I wanted to implement it this way, because SKNode does not have a `-insertChild:aboveChild:` or `insertChild:belowChild:` methods, and getting the target index and inserting there is a bit bug prone/confusing (in which direction does the existing node get "pushed"?).

Bit nevertheless, I gave in and decided to add/remove the parent layers on demand, just keeping track of the order (First-in-last-out, to preserve the intended layer order).

Enough talk, the code I settled for is:

```
#define GameSceneDefaultSingleFadeDuration 0.125f

- (void) pause:(id) sender
{
    [_effectNode setShouldEnableEffects:YES];

    [self addChild:_pauseLayer];
    [_pauseLayer addChild:_pauseCover];
    [_pauseCover setAlpha:0.0f];

    [_pauseCover runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.85
                                        duration:GameSceneDefaultSingleFadeDuration]
                completion:^(void){
                }];

    [self addChild:_dialogLayer];
    [_dialogLayer addChild:_pauseDialog];


    for (Button* button in [_pauseDialog children]) {
        [button setAlpha:0.0f];
        [button runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0f
                                       duration:GameSceneDefaultSingleFadeDuration]];
    }
}

- (void) resume:(id) sender
{
    // Unblur, fade white cover out and remove

    [_effectNode setShouldEnableEffects:NO];

    [_dialogLayer runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0f
                                         duration:GameSceneDefaultSingleFadeDuration]
                 completion:^(void){

                     [_dialogLayer removeAllChildren];
                     [_dialogLayer setAlpha:1.0f];
                     [_dialogLayer removeFromParent];
                 }];

    [_pauseCover runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0f
                                        duration:GameSceneDefaultSingleFadeDuration]
                completion:^(void){

                    [_pauseCover removeFromParent];
                    [_pauseLayer removeFromParent];
                }];
}
```

(`_pauseLayer` goes on top of the blurred game content, and `_dialogLayer` still on top of that, hosting the different dialogs: "Paused", "Confirm Quit", "Confirm Restart").

Comment: Test for any "ghost" layers, for example check any code path to make sure the _pauseLayer is only added once and not multiple times. Secondly I could imagine a retain cycle being an issue, because the block retains the _pauseLayer. Perhaps instead of running the code in the completion block do a performSelectorOnMainThread:afterDelay: that calls a selector performing the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks... I already scraped all this code and made something different, that seems to be working. Will be posting the code soon.

Comment: I have a method that logs the entire node hierarchy, from SKScene down. It is a recursive method with a `node` parameter and a `depth` parameter (to tab-indent). The outputs from before and after pausing/resuming the game are identical (save for timestamps), so there should be no ghost layer anywhere...

Comment: SpriteKit-Quicklook can help debug these things: https://github.com/KoboldKit/SpriteKit-QuickLook